# github actions main repository secret not picked up from pull request build

Tags: github, github-actions

I'm building out one of my company project through Github actions, in which we are running the workflow from latest pull request raised. I have notice one thing, whenever it tries to execute the secret from main the repository, its gives error as bad credentials.
Same stage when I tried to run from main repository it works fine. Do We have given some permissions to pull request to call secret from main repository.

Any suggestions will help.

Answer (score 11):

By default, pull-request builds don't get access to the secrets to prevent people from using the pull requests to exfiltrate your secrets through a change that reads the environment and sends the data somewhere else.

> Due to the dangers inherent to automatic processing of PRs, GitHub’s standard pull_request workflow trigger by default prevents write permissions and secrets access to the target repository. However, in some scenarios such access is needed to properly process the PR. To this end the pull_request_target workflow trigger was introduced.

See here for additional details:

- https://securitylab.github.com/research/github-actions-preventing-pwn-requests/

Comment: Even I have used the pull_request_target in workflow to make it work, but while running the pipeline through making changes in forked branch yaml file which require secret access to execute command. Eventually yaml file show no changes since it taking the yaml file from main repo.

Comment: Is there any example for this @prakasun I'm really not sure how to make my pull requests run with github action secrets

Comment: If you use `on: pull_request_target` your workflow well ha e access to the secrets. If you want the workflow to also run the yaml file of the pull request, you must check out the branch. The linked blogpost lists an insecure workaround by explicitly checking out the Sha of the pull request. This comes with great dangers as this gives the PR author the ability to access secrets and change the repo contents.

Comment: I tried using on: pull_request_target in my workflow but unfortunately it not picking up the secret from base branch.

Comment: have you rebased ?